# Changing Outgoing Links via HtAccess but with exceptions

Tags: .htaccess

Hi there on my site i link to a site that has changed the url of the site but uses the original domain to host the images. Is this possible to catch the links via htaccess but no change any of that domain with an image file detected?

So change outgoing link from www.oldsite.com to www.newsite.com but if images detected leave oldsite.com url.

I have too many links to change manually, is this even possible ?

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done using `.htaccess` . `.htaccess` is directory level Apache configuration file!